# What does 唯物史观 mean here?

Tags: meaning

I can't quite see what the phrase 唯物史观 really means here. Could someone please reformulate it with other words or just longer?

任何一门学科，包括理科，都是知识体系和价值体系的结合统一。物理学科的科学精神、唯物史观，不都是思想教育的重要内容吗？ 所以，教育工作者要有整体的育人观念。

In the text 科学精神 and 唯物史观 are separated with a listing comma '、' for which I use 'and'.

唯物： materialistic ??
史观： historically speaking ?? historical??

Maybe:
物理学科的科学精神、唯物史观，
the scientific mind of physics and (、) historical materialism,
不都是思想教育的重要内容吗？
are they not both important parts of ideological education?

Comment: 不都是思想教育的重要内容吗？ is a rhetorical question. I am not sure if 'Aren't they ...?' and 'Are they not ...' take the same effect in English, for I saw people use "Aren't they..." for a rhetorical question most of time.

Comment: 没有什么两样’aren't they' 和 ’are they not' 之间。 ’aren't they'也不一定修辞的

Comment: historical materialism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_materialism

Answer (score 1):

From the [wikepedia page](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8E%86%E5%8F%B2%E5%94%AF%E7%89%A9%E4%B8%BB%E4%B9%89):

> 历史唯物主义（英语：Historical Materialism）是马克思主义哲学的重要组成部分，也被称为唯物主义历史理论（materialist conception of history）或**唯物史观**。

Comment: 马克思先生不信奉上帝了吗？ 'Materialism' means you only believe in the physical world. Marx died before Quantum Mechanics really started, or he may have reconsidered!

Comment: @Pedroski, And he would reconsider more if he was still living now! lol

Comment: @Pedroski Things don't need to be match their name. For example, the Queen rules the United Kingdom, but really?